# Running impala sql script from Docker file

Tags: docker, cloudera, dockerfile, impala

I'm quite new to docker and I'm trying to do (I thought) a quite simple thing. As for the title I would like to run an impala script from a Docker file. Here my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM cloudera/quickstart:latest
COPY /home/dodo/script/ /home/cloudera/script
WORKDIR /home/cloudera/script
RUN service impala-state-store start \
    && service impala-catalog start \
    && service impala-server start \
    && impala-shell -f script.sql --quiet -i localhost
```

Building the image I keep having this error regarding impala-shell connection:

Error connecting: TTransportException, Could not connect to localhost:21000

I tried to run the same script with the same command inside the container and it works.

Do you have any idea how could I solve this issue, which host passing to the impala-shell?

Comment: Maybe you should wait a little until the port 21000 listens?

Comment: By the way, you should replace your `RUN` by an `ENTRYPOINT`

Comment: @user2915097 I tried waiting for the port, but it doesn't work

Comment: Sure, you need an ENTRYPOINT

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to add a few things

I created the following Dockerfile

`FROM cloudera/quickstart:latest
RUN mkdir /script
COPY service.sh /script
ENTRYPOINT  ["/script/service.sh"]`

with the file service.sh containing

`#!/bin/bash
service impala-state-store start \
&& service impala-catalog start \
&& service impala-server start \
&& impala-shell -f script.sql --quiet -i localhost`

then I build it

`docker build -t impala .`

and I run it

`docker run impala`

it shows

`Started Impala State Store Server (statestored):[  OK  ]
Started Impala Catalog Server (catalogd) :[  OK  ]
Started Impala Server (impalad):[  OK  ]
Starting Impala Shell without Kerberos authentication
Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'script.sql'`

So it still needs some work, such as providing the .sql file. You see that the ENTRYPOINT needs to launch the command that starts the container
`

Comment: my bad I didn't write my complete Dockerfile, I edited now the question, but my problem is not in executing the file. I copy the script to the container correctly I set WORKDIR to the directory containing the script and then I run the commands. The problem is more in the connection to impala, maybe I'm missing some services.